# On check box change value of the text box in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using datatable. where I am doing sum of the all the data in same column

Here is my code

```
                {
                    title: "New Price", data: "price",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {


                        return ' <input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" >
 <input type="number" id="newCost"  class ="price-input"  value="' + data + '" style="background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;">';

                    }

        function doSum5() {
           
            var nodes = table7.column(3).nodes();
            // get the value from each input field in each cell:
            var total = table7.column(3).nodes()
                // and then sum up the integer values:
                .reduce(function (sum, node) {
                    return sum + parseFloat($(node).find('input').val());
                }, 0);
            // place the sum in the relevant footer cell:
            var sum = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)
            $(table7.column(3).footer()).html(sum);


        }
```

[image]

Code is working fine, Now my question is how it is possible that only those fields will be selected for the sum which is checked for the checkbox. please guide me